# unable to update php7.3 to php7.4 on mac os catlina

Tags: php, homebrew

I have tried every solution to update php7.3 to 7.4 but it is not istalling

```
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
Warning: No available formula with the name "httpd" (dependency of shivammathur/php/php@7.4).
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
haydaraliawan@Haydars-MBP ~ %
```

please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`httpd` formula is part of the `homebrew/core` tap.

Make sure you have the core repo:

```
brew tap homebrew/core
```

Also, please run `brew doctor` and fix any reported issues.